# Rails 2.3.8 not displaying stack trace in browser, instead shows 500.html

Tags: ruby-on-rails

stack trace is not showing like it should (in the browser). Instead I get public/500.html rendered. The problem seems to be recreated when I created a new rails project and apply the haml plugin. Originally I though it was this ruby script causing the problem:

```
class ToHaml
  def initialize(path)
    @path = path
  end

  def convert!
    Dir["#{@path}/**/*.erb"].each do |file|
    `html2haml -rx #{file} #{file.gsub(/\.erb$/, '.haml')}`
    `rm #{file}`
    end
  end
end

path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'app', 'views')
ToHaml.new(path).convert!
```

I though it might have deleted an erb template used to show the stack trace. That doesn't appear to be the case because I can't find any template for that in app/views.

So it must be the haml plugin which is causing the problem

```
haml --rails MyRubyApp
```

Not sure how, but after I run this stack traces no longer display in the browser (just the 500.html). I've tried explicitly launching the server in development mode without any effect.

Anybody have insight on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem only occurs for errors with the controller. Every other error I encounter displays the trace. It also could have something to do with the models, the ones I've created are based off http://pastie.org/1124904 . The error which displays public/500.html occurs after submitting a form three chained models through the parent model's controller. The generated scaffold for the models works fine (with a few minor, and obvious tweaks). Its only the submitting of the chained form (using one submit button/controller).

Comment: Maybe status 500 error don't have a stack trace in rails 2.3?

Comment: Pulling apart the view code and stacking the fields_for blocks one at a time. This is giving me the stack traces I was looking for. My guess is if theres too many errors it wont show the trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to download an http sniffer and have a look at the post data. turns out there was a syntactic problem (although valid) in some of my view code (a pair of "[]" appended to a string which shouldn't have been there).

Hope this helps anyone experiencing the same kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me like you're running the new Rails application in the production environment rather than development. Check your RAILS_ENV variable and the environment.rb file to make sure that you are running in development, and not production.

Comment: My RAILS_ENV is set to development

Answer (score 0):

You may look for your error stack traces in log/development.log (or log/production.log if you're running in production, or whatever place you write your logs to).

Comment: It outputs to log/development.log and does not contain all the error information the stack trace does which is very useful information.